# how to use associateArray as a key in other associativeArray in PHP (just like using HashMap as key in another HashMap in JAVA)

Tags: java, php, hashmap

In Java, we can use HashMap as a key in other HashMap. I'm using an associative array as a map in PHP. Now there is a need to store an associative array as a key in another associative array.
I asked ChatGPT and it presented a lengthy solution:
Suppose $map is an array that I want to use as a key:

```
    ksort($map);
    $key = serialize($map);

    if(!isset($main[$key])){
        $main[$key] = 0;
    }
    $main[$key]++
```

I'm running above code in a loop where map is:

on first iteration: [a=>1, b=>2, c=>3]

on second iteration: [b=>2, a=>1, c=>3]

after 2 two iterations
main is looking like
$main["serialized---key"] -> 2

Yes, I need to use ksort because the next $map could contain the same array but keys could be in a different order.

The above solution is working fine but it will slow down drastically on large inputs. I need a better way where I don't need to use ksort and serialization.

I also used **spl_object_hash** instead of serialize but it didn't work. please suggest an optimal approach just like hashmap in java.
Also, I used **splObjectStorage** class by type-casting the array into an object but it gives incorrect results.

Detailed problem:

What I'm actually trying to do?
I'm solving the following problem:
Given an array of strings strs, group the anagrams together. You can return the answer in any order.

An Anagram is a word or phrase formed by rearranging the letters of a different word or phrase, typically using all the original letters exactly once.

Example 1:

Input: strs =

```
["eat","tea","tan","ate","nat","bat"]
```

Output:

```
[["bat"],["nat","tan"],["ate","eat","tea"]]
```

My working code:

In short, I'm just grouping the strings based on their frequency map.

```
function groupAnagrams(array $arr){
    $main = [];
    $ret = [];
    for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++){
        $el = $arr[$i];
        $map = [];
        for($j=0; $j<strlen($el); $j++){
            if(!isset($map[$el[$j]])){
                $map[$el[$j]]=0;
            }
            $map[$el[$j]]++;
        }
        ksort($map);
        $key = serialize($map);

        if(!isset($main[$key])){
            $main[$key] = [];
        }
        $main[$key][] = $el;
    }



    //return $main;
    foreach($main as $key=>$val){
        $ret[] = $val;
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Here is the problem link: https://leetcode.com/problems/group-anagrams/

Comment: It is better to tell us the data you have (with examples), then what you want it to become (with examples that match the previosu examples), then what you tried to majke that happen.

Comment: So show us the loop code. Show a `print_r()` of any input arrays. Make the output you require also look like a `print_r()` or similiar. If we can see what you statr with and what you want to finish up with, then we can try and help with the code to get you there

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just did without print_r
check the example test case

Comment: [As per the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php): "Arrays and objects _can not_ be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type." So you're either stuck with hashing yourself, or (probably nicer?) writing a task-appropriate datastructure instead of using maps.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans my code is working 100% fine but it will eventually slow down on if input is very big

Comment: That is the nature of runtime complexity. If you want to fix _that_, it's definitely time to write your own tree data structure with an ordered index that lets you efficiently find a keyed value anywhere in the tree.